# Как отсортировать двумерный массив по 1-ому элементу в массиве?

Tags: python, сортировка

Как отсортировать двумерный массив по 1-ому элементу в массиве, используя алгоритм сортировки пузырьком?

```
[[3, 2, 1, 4, 5],
[4, 2, 2, 3, 4],
[2, 2, 3, 2, 2],
[1, 3, 2, 5, 2],
[5, 3, 4, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Вы не знаете, где найти пузырёк, как сравнить первые элементы, или как обменять списки?

Comment: как сравнить первые элементы в вложенных массивах  и сортировать в порядке возрастания

Comment: Что может быть за проблема с первыми элементами? `if a[i][0] < a[j][0]:`

Comment: мне кажется вам надо чутка почитать в интернетеке что такое вложенные циклы и как с ними работать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот самый "примитивный" пузырек для 2-мерного списка:

```
def comparasion(a, b):
    return a > b

def bubble_sort(array):
    for j in range(len(array)-1):
        for i in range(len(array)-1):
            if comparasion(array[i][0], array[i+1][0]):
                array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
    return array

array = [
    [3, 2, 1, 4, 5],
    [4, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 2, 3, 2, 2],
    [1, 3, 2, 5, 2],
    [5, 3, 4, 2, 1],
]

print(bubble_sort(array))
```